# Twitter Bootstrap - Grid layout that doesn't stack until mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap 3, how would I design a basic 2 column grid with main content on the left and a sidebar on the right, that DOESNT stack until mobile view?

Comment: Have you looked at the specific classes? [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) and [Bootstrap responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) `.col-xs-` won't wrap until mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Explanation here -> http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/

Essentially .col- followed by the first size going up you DON'T want to stack -(12 divided by the number of columns you want)

In your case .col-sm-6

Comment: great link and explanation, it's just what I needed!